# Show the IEEE754 single-precision representation of the decimal number 23.45. Show your work and indicate the 3 parts of the representation

Tags: computer-science, binary

So, I've did some work.. Not sure if it's right. Please confirm for me if I did the calculations right. Thanks!

23.45
(focus on 23 part)

22 = 11 * 2 + 1

11 = 5 * 2 + 1

5 = 2 * 2 + 1

2 = 2 * 2 + 0

so this part should be 0111 ...

(.45 part)

.45 * 2 = 0.9

.9 * 2 = 1.8

.8 * 2 = 1.6

.6 * 2 = 1.2

.2 * 2 = 0.4

.4 * 2 = 0.8

.8 * 2 = 1.6

.6 * 2 = 1.2

.2 * 2 = 0.4

.4 * 2 = 0.8

so this part is 0111001100

...
So the whole number should 0111.01110011 with a bar over 0011 at the end

Moving the point left
1.1101110011 x (2^-2)

This is the part where I get confused...

3 parts of representation:

S = 0

O = 2

M = 1101110011

Is this right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you! I was kind of lost so I went on the web to see if I could solve it after I posted. I put my work in the body now.

Comment: It may help you to read first about [scientific notation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/scientific-notation.html) and then come back to [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).  Then ping me if you still have questions.

Comment: $23$ in binary is $1011_2$.  You should be working in **powers** of $2$...  Also an (not subnormal) IEEE-754 representation has an implicit leading bit, so you will only see the bits $011_2$ coming from the $23$.